# How can I make an off-chain call to get the data stored at a specific storage slot on-chain?

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation, storage, ethers.js, slots

I want to get data from on-chain that is not explicitly available through a getter. For example, if I know that there is data at position `0x360894a13ba1a3210667c828492db98dca3e2076cc3735a920a3ca505d382bbc` at address `0xd0A7333587053A5BAe772BD37b9AAe724E367619`, how can I retrieve that data if there is no getter function in the contract?

Comment: Yes, the _answer_ is the same, however the question is being asked is different. Someone may be looking for the answer to this question, but may not find the other questions based on search results. Similarly, a search for the other question would most certainly not produce this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can retrieve any piece of data from any on-chain contract if you know the location that the data is stored. You can do this by using the `getStorage` RPC call or through any web3 library.

---

For your specific question, you can retrieve the data a few ways:

ethers.js

```
> ethersProvider.getStorageAt('0xd0A7333587053A5BAe772BD37b9AAe724E367619', '0x360894a13ba1a3210667c828492db98dca3e2076cc3735a920a3ca505d382bbc')

0x00000000000000000000000020af9e54a3670ef6a601bca1f1ec22b1f93cbe23
```

web3.js:

```
> web3.eth.getStorageAt('0xd0A7333587053A5BAe772BD37b9AAe724E367619', '0x360894a13ba1a3210667c828492db98dca3e2076cc3735a920a3ca505d382bbc')

0x00000000000000000000000020af9e54a3670ef6a601bca1f1ec22b1f93cbe23
```

bash:

```
> curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0", "method": "eth_getStorageAt", "params": ["0xd0A7333587053A5BAe772BD37b9AAe724E367619", "0x0", "latest"], "id": 1}' localhost:8545

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":"0x00000000000000000000000020af9e54a3670ef6a601bca1f1ec22b1f93cbe23"}
```